# Subcategories with the same name in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category table like this:

[image]

I can list categories as list and subcategories as dropdown list but My designer send me a design that categories have subcategories with the same name:

[image]

How can I manage this type of subcategories?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me a "design" issue rather than a database issue.

You can add a dash symbol before the subcategories names in the dropdown, so the options values would be:

```
Category 1
  -Subcategory 1
  -Subcategory 2
Category 2
  -Subcategory 1
  -Subcategory 2
```

My appending " -" before the subcategory's title, you are creating levels in the dropdown, which the user can visually see, and recognize where each subcategory belong to.

It's not a perfect solution, but it's sure easy to implement. If you're willing to spend time on it, try research jquery plugins that have multi level select boxes support, such as http://php4bd.wordpress.com/2007/07/15/javascript-controlled-dependent-or-cascading-select-list/

Answer (score 0):

You have id to uniquely identify your tuples. Duplicated names aren't a problem.

Also read: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: yes, but when I add sub category in admin panel, I have list them withe the name not id.

Comment: i belive your admin panel uses id internally to manage it. Also what's your problem? if you don't know which of them are just echo the id too near the name

Comment: when you add catgory in admin panel, you have select a sub category from dropdown menu. In dropdown menu, there is two "finished" sub category that belongs to "hotel" and "home" categories. How can user know that what "finished" belongs to "home" or "hotel"?

Comment: @utopia what kind of bad admin panel do you have? the data should be shown in some hierarchical way so you can easy see where subcategory belongs

Comment: this is my own bad admin. But if you have any good admin that could help me, please give me. Thanks

Comment: @utopia: any good admin? lol what are you talking about?.. If you need a CMS go with drupal.org, with drupal you will not have to worry about these bad design

Comment: I want to use and develope my own panel. BTW, @aporat's answer has solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @utopia: you asked for any good admin and then you said you want your own.. ok